# Limits of sum integral in exponential form

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm stuck with this limit of sum integral. Couldn't find the pattern, what's the most efficient way to solve this?

$\lim \limits_{n \to ∞} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}+1}$

$\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$

$b-a=1$

I know that using right riemann sum, $f(a+k\Delta x) = \frac{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}+1}$, please advice on how can I continue.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because you want to evaluate limit with X as variable but the question doesn't have any X term in it

Comment: What's $x$ in $$\lim \limits_{x \to ∞} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}+1}$$

Comment: sorry, its n, i've edited it. @Manthanein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_k=\dfrac{k}{n}$$
$$\Delta x_k=x_{k+1}-x_{k}=\dfrac{k+1}{n}-\dfrac{k}{n}=\dfrac{1}{n}$$
then with
$$f(x)=\dfrac{a^{1+x}}{a^{1+x}+1}$$
we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}+1}
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(x_k)\Delta x_k \\
&= \int_0^1 f(x) dx \\
&= \int_0^1\dfrac{a^{1+x}}{a^{1+x}+1}dx \\
&= \left(\dfrac{1}{\ln a}\ln|a^{1+x}+1|\right)_0^1 \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\ln a}\ln\dfrac{a^2+1}{a+1}
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know xk = k/n?